# ObjectBox Query with strings

Tags: objectbox

How it is possible to create a QUERY using GREATER option with strings?
I see that this is possible only for numeric or data properties.
I have data coming from an IBM legacy database where dates are saved in timestamp fornat "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".
So, to test if a date is less or greater of a given date I have to compare two strings.

Comment: Please show an example of the data that you want to query and the expected results.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We missed that one. I just opened a [ticket](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/433) for this so you can track this feature. We'll try to support this shortly.

PS.: For your use case, you could have a long timestamp or Date property additionally.

Answer (score 0):

With the new versions of Objectbox this is now possible.

Example with Dates:

```
// you should define the lowest possible date as string
String lowestDate = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(3).toString();

getMyAlbumBox().query().greater(ObjectToQuery_.date, lowestDate).build()
```